# RDS How to Set Mysql Timezone on Slave Replication

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, master-slave

I'm trying to create a slave mysql database on Amazon RDS. I had problems setting the timezone but I managed to fix this by using these tricks on this URL: [Here](http://www.parhasard.net/entry/2011/07/06/17:37/)

But somehow when I started to listen on the masterdb, I realize the dates are not being set correctly.

Is there any way to make RDS slave reads right dates from mysql binary logs?

Comment: I don't understand are you writing to the slave? The slave is supposed to have an exact replica from the master, with timestamps and everything. And the idea is that you write to the master(s) so the slaves are always in sync.

Comment: @Rico Yes I am. RDS Slave is 1 day behind from master while slave try to catch master, some SQL queries inside of binary logs' has NOW() function. That's why I get time difference between master and RDS slaves on some values.